# Parse no response with nested/chained saves

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

So I have two objects which I am saving. However, I want to store a reference to one of the object (lets call it a) on the other (b) so I am saving 'a' first and then once the save is complete, saving object 'b' after setting the reference into its proper field. However, though it seems like response.success line is being hit, the success/error function is not triggered on the caller. It just hangs and timesout.

The caller code looks as follows

```
  Parse.Cloud.run('createObject', params).then( 
    (success) => { //neither are called, timeout results
      console.log("Success!");
    }, (error) => { //neither are called, timeout results
      console.log("Error!");
    }
  );
```

The snippet of code from 'createObject' that causes no response to be sent

```
    newA.save().then(function(objA) {
      newB.set('refA', objA);
      return newB.save();
    }, function(error) {
      response.error(
            utils.sformat(
              'Error saving new A with params {1}: {0}',
              JSON.stringify(request.params),
              JSON.stringify(error)
            )
          );
    }).then(function(objB) {
      response.success({
        b: objB
      });
    }, function(error) {
      response.error(
            utils.sformat(
              'Error saving new B with params {1}: {0}',
              JSON.stringify(request.params),
              JSON.stringify(error)
            )
          );
    });
```

Now if I do something like a batch save and have an array of objectA and objectB and call Parse.Object.saveAll, it goes through and there is a response... but I can't exactly use that if I want that reference to be set. I'm puzzled as to why there the response does not get sent when saves are chained/nested like that.

The biggest issue I have is that the objects both get created and saved 100% correctly and properly. So I'm really not sure why this code hangs.

Edit: I forgot to mention but objectA has an aftersave trigger. But atm all it does is print out some test lines and disabling it hasn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: First parameter passed to `Parse.Cloud.run()` should be String. What type is `createObject`?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is a string. The command works fine. Everything works fine. The objects both get created and saved properly. The only issue is that the caller does not receive a response.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works. The problem was that I had a function within the response.success call that was being made to format the object before sending it back but I was getting a nullpointexception due to something I was trying to access. I didn't turn on verbose logging so parse never told me that this was happening.

The code above works fine as it stands.